# Ordering guarantee in GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I happen to dig into C and lock free programming. Fiddling with it I wonder what guarantee gcc can give me that a program is executed the exact same way I write it down and no register optimization is performed in a certain step and no operation is changed in its ordering.

As I currently understand it, it guarantees that memory operations happen in the very same order and that method calls happen in the same order along with themself and memory operations. In between reordering might ocure.

The register optimization can be switched off by using the volatile keyword.

Are there any additional guarantees or corner cases that C and especially gcc has implied?

Comment: AFAIK a compiler is only required to not change the meaning (i.e. external observable behavior) of a program. As C programmer you cannot really control the memory operations (a compiler may omit or insert an operation). Even if the compiler just emit the code as you wrote it, it is of no use. You should read of [Out Of Order Execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) and [Memory barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier), along with serializing and atomic instructions for more information.

Comment: The C standard allows implementations certain freedom to re-order operations. I don't think there is a well defined single thing that is 'the exact same way I write it down'. So will it execute in the same way every time - yes (the compiled code defines a fixed order of execution). Is that the exact same way you wrote it down - undefined.

Comment: The short answer: there is no guarantee whatsoever.

Comment: The C11 standard adds a lot of stuff to give the programmer fine control over memory ordering and such things. I recommend you to look for a document called N1570, the latest draft of the C11 standard, which is available for free. Give it a good read!

Answer (score 3):

**A compiler is only required to not change the meaning of a program.**

The meaning of a program is given by the semantic of its C statements, for example the`volatile` qualifier is a way to reificate at the semantic level the interaction with external agents.
`volatile` alone however is useless when it comes to threads synchronization, it has *local* effects only.

So you should only imply what the standard of C implies, if the standard given no ordering semantic to a statement nor any side effect, then there is none.

In order to optimize out some code the compiler **has to prove** that the optimization doesn't change the meaning.
This is in general an hard (or even undecidable) problem, so it is done only in simple context.

Consider

```
#include <stdio.h>

int simple(const int a, const int b)
{
    int c = a + b;              //3x Memory operation?
    int d = c*c;                //2x Memory operation?

    return d+d;                 //Memory operation?

}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;                  //Memory operation?
    int b = 0;                  //Memory operation?

    a = simple(2, 3);           //Function call + Memory operation?
    b = simple(3, 4);           //Function call + Memory operation?

    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);    //Function call + 3x Memory operation?

    return 0;
}
```

The C standard dictates that `a = simple(2, 3);` is executed before `b = simple(3, 4);` as the end of an expression is a sequence point.

This is the code generated by gcc with full optimization

```
lea    0x18f0(%rip),%rcx        # 0x100403030, "%d %d\n"
mov    $0x62,%r8d                                  
mov    $0x32,%edx                                  
callq  0x100401110 <printf>
```

I used cygwin, so the ABI is Windows's one. This is equivalent to

```
printf("%d %d\n", 50, 98);
```

This is an ad hoc example,  the function `simple` is **pure** and takes **compile time constant expressions**, so the result is known at compile time.
**This is the proof that gcc needed to optimized out the calls**.

---

In writing lock free code you shouldn't worry about compiler optimizations at all as long as you use the correct semantic (e.g. `volatile` for having read-write accesses as side effects **for the sake of optimization only**).

What you **really should** be worried about is [memory ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering) as pointed out in my comment.
C11 finally reificates all this in its [memory model](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order).

Comment: You answer is wrong in using volatile keyword! There is no guarantee that any access to the variable is depended on any other variable. Especially on multi threaded applications volatile is simply useless. You must use any kind of statement which generates memory barriers to synchronize your access to the memory. volatile is not doing this!

Comment: @Klaus who said so? `volatile` is used for treating read-write accesses as side effects for the sake of **optimization**, re read the whole paragraph. I explicitly mention the memory model of C11 as the only way to synchronize threads.

Comment: You wrote "external agents" which is maybe misunderstood by me. The only thing `volatile` is useful is to say something like "the memory can be modified externally out of the control of the actual seen code". That has nothing to do with memory barriers and ordering. Because OP asks for lockfree implementations he asked especially for multi threading. So there is a need for memory barriers at all and volatile is not a helpful part of the answer. Only my two cents.

Comment: @Klaus "the memory can be modified externally out of the control of the actual seen code" and "external agents" seem pretty close to me :) The OP asked about the optimizations made by the compiler, this is where `volatile` came useful. I've tried to point out that the compiler know how to optimize and so that is not a concern (you have to use the right qualifiers however) but the memory model is. We are saying the same thing, after all :) maybe I should change some lines in my answer. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

If your code depends on not reordering the operations and do not any other optimization it is simply "undefined behavior".

If you search for such guarantees you simply search for a guarantee that you write a broken program which executes correct. You should use the semantic which is represented by your used language. If you need assumptions on how the language implements the actions on a given os and machine, you are totally on the wrong path!

If you actually have some kind of guarantee for a actual compiler version and a used underlaying os this will not be guaranteed in the feature! So the wording "guarantee" is also not really true. If it must the simple answer is: There is no guarantee at all! The language have a semantic and the compiler guarantee to implement it. Not more at all!.

Comment: So basically I have even no guarantee that setting a pointer and setting the other point with independent values occure in the very same ordering. That would render most of the implementations for lock free datastructures in C and C++ to be broken by design. Finding those assumptions even in reference implementations especially if one think about compilers to inline methods at random (unpredictable) to be broken as well. So are all those libs broken?

Comment: It is right that setting two unrelated pointers can be reordered and also optimized away. If some libraries depends on this, they are broken by design. BUT: If there is any lock free mechanism inside there is a place where the two pointers are compared or used in any other manner. At this place the semantic guarantees that both pointers are set ( or the comparison operation is optimized in any other way to fulfill  the semantic of the code ). So there is nothing which relates on reordering. Without giving us an example of your code you look in, we can not give you an answer if it is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Ordering guarantees between threads in C are only achievable with `stdatomic.h` from C11 or compiler-specific extensions. In all other cases the only thing that the compiler needs to guarantee is that the externally visible behavior of the program (this could be roughly translated to: function calls and references to memory not under the compilers control) is the same as interpreted according to the standard. Before C11 threads didn't exist from the point of view of the C standard, so it didn't concern itself with threaded behavior.